# Integrate UIKit-based app into SwiftUI-based app : "Multiple commands produce ..."

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm trying to integrate [this UIKit-based app](https://github.com/hoiberg/HM10-BluetoothSerial-iOS) into SwiftUI based project. I want to add this app as a view in the new SwiftUI project, but when I drag the UIKit project's files into SwiftUI Project, it returns `Multiple commands produce '/Users/jh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hm10port-hdaapksgtqpvrecxcwrtcdfnzhwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/hm10port.build/Debug-iphoneos/hm10port.build/Objects-normal/arm64/BluetoothSerial.stringsdata'` error.

Also, I tried to port only the backend to the SwiftUI-based app, but the backend uses UIKit and Storyboard grammar, so I couldn't integrate it.

I tried to integrate with this code:

```swift
struct MySwiftUIView: UIViewRepresentable {
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIViewType {
    let view = UIView()
    return view
  }
    
  func updateUIView(_ view: UIViewType, context: Context) {
  }
}
```